# When should "dough" be used?

Tags: meaning-in-context, when

I've heard in many movies/songs, specially in American English, that they add to the end of sentences the word "dough". For instance:

> I won´t play today dough

Could anyone give me a hint - what does this mean exactly and when it can be used?

Comment: It is "though",  Not "dough". 
It means  in spite of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you are looking for is actually "Though"

Which can be defined as

> despite the fact that;

Here is an example sentence.

> I am a history student, I don't like that subject though.

It means I don't like history despite the fact that I am a student of that subject.